# Linking to jQuery tabs from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I added tabs to a section of a page I am working on (stridertechnologies.com/stoutwebsite/products.php)using the javascript below. I'm new to javascript, but fluent in html/css.

I want to link to the different tabs from the home page, but I am not sure how to do that outside of anchor names with id's in html and that doesn't seem to work with this.

It seems like there should be something really simple I can add to detect which link they clicked on and make it the active tab. This site is supposed to go live this weekend, and this is the only thing the client has asked me to do. Thanks for the help.

Edit: The answer linked above does not work.

Javascript-

```
;(function($){
  $.fn.html5jTabs = function(options){
    return this.each(function(index, value){
      var obj = $(this),
      objFirst = obj.eq(index),
      objNotFirst = obj.not(objFirst);

      $("#" +  objNotFirst.attr("data-toggle")).hide();
      $(this).eq(index).addClass("active");

      obj.click(function(evt){

        toggler = "#" + obj.attr("data-toggle");
        togglerRest = $(toggler).parent().find("div");

        togglerRest.hide().removeClass("active");
        $(toggler).show().addClass("active");

        //toggle Active Class on tab buttons
        $(this).parent("div").find("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        return false; //Stop event Bubbling and PreventDefault
      });
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

script in head tag-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".tabs a").html5jTabs();
    });
</script>
```

Html-

```
        <div id="tabwrapper" class="grid_12">
            <div class="tabs">
                <a data-toggle="tile">Tile</a>
                <a data-toggle="metal">Metal</a>
                <a data-toggle="shingle">Shingle</a>
                <a data-toggle="flat">Flat</a>
                <a data-toggle="custom">Custom Projects</a>
            </div>
            <div class="tabContent">
                <div id="tile" class="content_tab grid_12">
                    <h2>Brands of Tile Roofing Offered</h2>
                    <p>We offer many different types of Tile Roofing. These brands listed here are a few of main brands of Tile used in Southern Utah. Tile roofing is becoming more popular here in Southern Utah, and the majority of newly built homes have tile roofs.</p>
                    <div class="grid_6 alpha omega logocontainer">
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.boralna.com/rooftiles/rooftiles.asp"><img src="products/borallogo.jpg" alt="Boral Logo" title="Boral Logo" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_6 alpha omega logocontainer">
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.eagleroofing.com/"><img src="products/eaglelogo.gif" alt="Eagle standard" title="Eagle standard" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div id="metal" class="content_tab grid_12">
                    <h2>Brands of Metal Roofing Offered</h2>
                    <p>Many different types of Custom Metal Roof systems are available.      </p>

                    <div class="grid_4 alpha omega logocontainer">
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.fabral.com/"><img src="products/fabrallogo.png" alt="Fabral Logo" title="Fabral Roofing" /></a>

                         <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.ascbp.com/
"><img src="products/asclogo.png" alt="ASC Logo" title="ASC Roofing Products" /></a>

                        </div>
                        <div class="grid_8 alpha omega logocontainer">
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://firestonebpco.com/roofing/metal-roofing-systems/"><img src="products/firestonelogo.jpg" alt="Firestone Logo" title="Firestone" /></a>
                    </div>


                 </div>

                <div id="shingle" class="content_tab grid_12">
                    <h2>Brands of Shingles Offered</h2>
                    <p>Many different types of Shingle Roofing are available. The brands listed here are a few of main brands of Shingles used in Southern Utah. </p>
                    <div class="grid_4 alpha omega logocontainer">
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.gaf.com/"><img src="products/gaflogo.jpg" alt="GAF Logo" title="GAF Materials Corporation" /></a>
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.certainteed.com/"><img src="products/certainteedlogo.jpg" alt="Certainteed Logo" title="Certainteed Roofing" /></a>
                        </div>
                    <div class="grid_4 alpha omega logocontainer">
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.pabcoroofing.com/
"><img src="products/pabcologo.png" alt="Pabco Logo" title="Pabco" /></a>

                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.owenscorning.com/"><img src="products/owenscorninglogo.jpg" alt="Owens Logo" title="Owens Corning" /></a>

                      </div>  
                    <div class="grid_4 alpha omega logocontainer">
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.tamko.com/"><img src="products/tamko.gif" alt="Tamko Logo" title="Tamko Roofing Products" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div id="flat" class="content_tab grid_12">
                    <h2>Brands of Flat Roofing Offered</h2>
                    <p>As with all the other roofing types, there are many different types of Flat Roof systems. The brands listed here are a few of main Flat roof systems we use.</p>
                    <div class="grid_4 alpha omega logocontainer">
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.durolast.com/"><img src="products/durolast.jpg" alt="Duro-Last Logo" title="Duro-Last Roofing Inc." /></a>
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.versico.com/"><img src="products/versicologo.jpg" alt="Versico Logo" title="Versico" /></a>

                        </div>
                    <div class="grid_4 alpha omega logocontainer">
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.specjm.com/commercial/roofing.asp"><img src="products/johnsmanville.jpg" alt="Johns Manville Logo" title="Johns Manville" /></a>                                   
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.ibroof.com/"><img src="products/iblogo.jpg" alt="IB Logo" title="IB Roof Systems" /></a>

                        </div>
                    <div class="grid_4 alpha omega logocontainer"> 
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.weatherbondroofing.com/"><img src="products/weatherbondlogo.jpg" alt="Weatherbond Logo" title="Weatherbond" /></a>   

                    </div>                                         
                </div>

                <div id="custom" class="content_tab grid_12">
                    <h2>Custom Roofing Options</h2>
                    <p>At Stout Roofing, we are able to create any custom design to match your dream home or business. Visit our Project Gallery to see some examples.</p>

                    <div class="grid_6 alpha omega logocontainer">
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.classicmetalroofingsystems.com/"><img src="products/classiclogo.png" alt="Classic Metals Logo" title="Classic Metals" /></a>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="grid_6 alpha omega logocontainer">
                        <a class="logo" target="_blank" href="http://www.decra.com/"><img src="products/decralogo.jpg" alt="Decra Logo" title="Decra" /></a>
                    </div>  

                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: RELATED : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818754/link-directly-to-a-jquery-tab-from-another-page?rq=1 AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636848/linking-to-a-specific-tab-from-another-page?rq=1

Comment: The second link doesn't seem to have a ranked answer. The first link would mean I'd have to rewrite all my current code for the jquery tab ui, I'd rather not have to rewrite it all, but work with what I have done. If I have to though, I will. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, not sure where to put it in my javascript file without it messing up the rest of it. Seems to do nothing no matter where I place it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the tab div id in the url from the link and use that to select.

Home page links from index.html:

```
<a href="products.php?tabId=tile">tile</a>
<a href="products.php?tabId=metal">metal</a>
```

Add this javascript to the tab page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// To get parameter from url
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
    attrNameStart: function (el, i, props) {
        var hasAttribute = false;
        $.each(el.attributes, function (i, attr) {
            if (attr.name.indexOf(props[3]) !== -1) {
                hasAttribute = true;
                return false;
            }
        });


        return hasAttribute;
    }
});

// deselect tabs and select the tab by id
function focusTab(id) {
    $("#tile").hide().removeClass("active");
    $("#metal").hide().removeClass("active");
    $("#shingle").hide().removeClass("active");
    $("#flat").hide().removeClass("active");
    $("#custom").hide().removeClass("active");
    var toggle = $(id).parent().find("div");
    toggle.hide().removeClass("active");
    $('a:attrNameStart(data-toggle)').removeClass("active");
    var id1 = getParameterByName("tabId");
    var toggler = $('*[data-toggle=' + id1 + ']');        
    $(toggler).addClass("active");        
    $(id).show().addClass("active");
}

 $(function() {
    $(".tabs a").html5jTabs();

    // Get the tab id from the url
    var tabId = "#" + getParameterByName("tabId");
    // Focus the tab       
    focusTab(tabId);
});
</script>
```

EDIT: Replace the original `focusTab` function with the edit.  Also add the extend function `attrNameStart`.  This should deselect the default active tab.
EDIT2: `focusTab` had a bug, it should work now

** I looked at your site and my solutions seems to be working for you.  One thing I noticed.  You initialize the `html5jTabs()` twice.

Remove the first call at the top

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".tabs a").html5jTabs();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! This is working somewhat. It is leaving the first tab highlighted as active, though, instead of the one that is actually active.

Comment: Do this answer could apply to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807815/i-know-html5-css-but-new-to-javascript-i-dont-know-how-to-link-to-tabs-with-j  ?

Comment: To toggle active/inactive classes use `$('.active').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active');` Also, if the answer here has solved your problem, please mark answer as accepted and upvote.  Thank you.

Comment: This is working quite well. It is hiding any images I have in the tab content, however. It leaves text. Strange.

Comment: @Brocksley, good to see it's working.  I checked your site and you're using my solution.  Can you mark my answer as accepted please.  Also, in your code, you initialize `$(".tabs a").html5jTabs();` twice.  Remove the first one.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate by @MilchePatern but the other question was asked by the same person and not solved.  My answer is being used as the solution on his site, not even an upvote?

Comment: @user3123649 It's still hiding the images in my tab content. Can't figure that out. Why would it be hiding the images, but displaying the text? I think it's this line:     toggle.hide().removeClass("active");

Comment: Figured it out. The child divs were causing problems with it. I changed them to spans and everything works now. Thanks a million @user3123649 I can't up vote yet, but you deserve it. Thanks!

Comment: @user3123649 Don't worry about your reputation, focus on giving good answers, be carefull about duplication and be honest. The rest will come by itself.

Comment: @MilchePatern I see what you're trying to say and it seems noble. Except, I provided a good answer that is being used as the solution. I'm not sure that pointing out several times that this is a duplicate is helpful unless it leads to an answer. The supposed duplicates didn't have useful answers.  As for reputation, this site works on the reward system and there's a good reason for that.  It encourages participation and better, quicker answers.  I don't see what you mean about honesty. Unless that's something you've dealt previously here.

Comment: Have you seen the other dupe? I mooved your question mentioning about the dupe trying to help. If it was not the proper way, i am sure i will be guided to do better next time. About beeing honest, nothing in particular, just basic greetings and encouragements.

Comment: Ok thanks.  When I first saw the other duplicate it had no answer.  Just trying to help here.